# Obtener el primer elemento de un array con AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, djangorestframework, rest

Estoy iniciándome en [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) y ya pude crear mi primera API con [djangorestframework](/questions/tagged/djangorestframework).

Tengo esta factoría y un controlador para consumir los datos:

```
(function(){
  "use strict";

  angular.module('core.controllers', [])
    .controller('CMIUtils', CMIUtils)
    .factory("PolicyFactory", PolicyFactory);

  CMIUtils.$inject = ['$scope', 'PolicyFactory'];
  PolicyFactory.$inject = ['$resource'];

  function CMIUtils($scope, PolicyFactory) {
    $scope.date = new Date();
    $scope.politicas = PolicyFactory.get();
  }

  function PolicyFactory($resource) {
    return $resource(
      "/api/v1.0/politica/",
      {},
      { 'get': {method: "GET", isArray: false}}
    );
  }
})();
```

En mi página, uso `<li ng-controller="CMIUtils">{$ politicas.results $}</li>` y lo que obtengo, por supuesto es esto:

```
<li ng-controller="CMIUtils" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
  [
    {"revision":4,"fecha":"2016-04-16","politica":"Esta es la cuarta política"},
    {"revision":3,"fecha":"2016-04-04","politica":"Esta es la tercera política"},
    {"revision":2,"fecha":"2016-04-02","politica":"Esta es la segunda política"},
    {"revision":1,"fecha":"2016-04-01","politica":"Esta es la primera política"}
  ]
</li>
```

La lista, como tal, la usaré en otro momento con `ng-repeat`, pero en este momento, **quisiera saber como obtener el primer elemento de esta lista**.

> No digo como obtener el *detalle*, solo el primer elemento de una lista cualquiera generada con el método `.factory()`.

Comment: ¿podrias ser más específico con respecto a obtener el primer elemento? ¿Te refieres únicamente a mostrarlo en la vista, desde el controlador o desde el factory? En todo caso, @WilfredoP ya puso la respuesta de como obtener el primer elemento de un `Array`

Comment: Efectivamente, me refiero a mostrar el primer elemento en la vista. La respuesta de @WilfredoP es lo que necesito. También cambié el título para que sea coherente con la pregunta y la respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener el primer registro debes hacer:

```
<li ng-controller="CMIUtils">{$ politicas.results[0] $}</li>
```